# getSelectedItemPosition() of ListView returns -1

Tags: android, listview, selecteditem

With this code, when System.out.println is executed after setSelection instruction, returns -1 and I don't know why.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.composition);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        cabecera = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cabecera);
        information = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.paciente);

        proceso = new ArrayList<>();
        proceso.add("- Item1");
        proceso.add("- Item2");

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.customizedlistitem,proceso);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lv.setSelected(true);
                lv.setSelection(0);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                System.out.println("Selected Item onCreate: "+lv.getSelectedItemPosition());
                System.out.println("Get Count en onCreate: "+lv.getCount());
            }
        });

        nextBundle = new Bundle();
        nextBundle.putString("name",proceso.get(position));

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Check.class);
                in.putExtras(nextBundle);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
    }
```

getCount() function applied to the ListView returns a correct value: 2

I have searched to find a solution but all that I have read and tested don't solve the problem.

**UPDATE:**

This code:

```
listPacientes = new ArrayList<>();
listPacientes.add("Elemento 1");
listPacientes.add("Elemento 2");
listPacientes.add("Elemento 3");

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.customizedlistitem,list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.setSelection(1);
System.out.println(lv.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

works on Main Activity. That "System.out" returns 1, but the same code in next Activities, returns -1, why? I can't understand it.

Comment: I think lv.getSelectedItemPosition() will work in listview.onitemselectedlistener...

Answer (score 0):

you are first selecting the cell and afterwards refreshing the ListView by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` - this way your selection is removed.

Comment: I've removed that instruction and the program is still with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `lv.getSelectedItemPosition()` method inside `onItemClick()` method. you will get the proper value here

Comment: Thanks, I will test it.
But, I don't know why, in other Activity with practically the same code, the function returns a correct value.. :(